# Reporting Services: How to get the display value of the selected parameter

Tags: reporting-services

Let say I have a list of months to be selected from. Key would be the ordinal number of the month, value would be the name of the month. Later when rendering the report, I need to display the value selected, so if user selected January, that is what should be displayed. How do i get a reference to this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Parameters!ParameterName.Label
```